# IIS Virtual Directory - Issues with Authentication

Tags: windows, iis, windows-authentication, virtual-directory

I have an Active Directory domain lab set up with AutomatedLab (Bunch of Hyper-V VMs) to test some web server configurations. Domain is `CONTOSO`.

I am currently testing out Virtual Directories on the web server (`web1.contoso`). In terms of authorization, here is how it's currently configured:

```
|-- MACHINE: Anonymous authentication (other auth disabled)
    |-- Default Web Site: Anonymous authentication (other auth disabled)
        |-- Virtual Directory (name: example): Windows authentication (other auth disabled)
```

The windows authentications providers from top to bottom are "NTLM" and "Negotiate".

I am using `DefaultAppPool` as the application pool for the default web site and virtual directory. The pool identity is `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

I have created a corresponding file directory for the "example" virtual directory at c:\example on the web server. I gave it the following folder permissions with no inheritance:

| User/Group | Permissions | Entity Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ConfigManagement | Read/Write | AD group. Any user that belongs to the Config Management group. |
| IIS_IUSRS | Read | iis_iusr group. |
| Administrators (WEB1\Administrators) | Read/Write | Default group. |
| System | Read/Write | Default group. |
| Users (WEB1\Users) | Read/Write | Default group. |

When I visit the virtual directory on localhost (while remoted onto `web1.CONTOSO` as a server admin), I was successful and was able to see the index.html I placed in there.

Using a Windows 10 VM `client1.CONTOSO`, I logged on as a normal user; the user is a member of the `ConfigManagement` security group and also a domain user. When I visit the virtual directory at `https://web1.CONTOSO/example`, I end up getting a pop up asking for the user's credentials. Entering it will repeatedly make the pop up window re-appear until I cancel, which then I receive a 401.2 unauthorized error on the browser.

Checking the Failed Trace logging, it seems to ignore the fact that I have configured Windows Authentication for the virtual directory and fails with authenticating?

[image: Failed Tracing Error]

Here is a portion of the stack trace that might be relevant:

[image: Portion of the stack trace]

I have tried to change the authentication at the web site and machine level to Windows Authentication, restarted the `web1.CONTOSO` server VM, but it still exhibits the same issues when a client tries to access the virtual directory.

My initial assumption that enabling windows authentication and disabling anonymous authentication on the virtual directory itself should be more than sufficient, but that seems to not be the case. I'm not sure how to proceed from here or if I missed anything.

Edit:

Web.config for the virtual directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
                    <providers>
                        <clear />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>
            </authentication>
        </security>
        <tracing>
            <traceFailedRequests>
                <remove path="*" />
                <add path="*">
                    <traceAreas>
                        <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                        <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    </traceAreas>
                    <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="200-999" />
                </add>
            </traceFailedRequests>
        </tracing>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The windows authentication settings on the virtual directory:

[image: Windows authentication on the virtual directory]

Comment: You should enable FRT to track all 401 responses, not only 401.2. Then you are going to see what happens. The actual error occurs when you see the first few prompts, not when you cancel and see 401.2.

Comment: HTTP error 401.2 unauthorized indicates that you are not licensed to view a certain page as a result of invalid verification headers, this is triggered by the incorrect configuration of IIS, can you share the relevant configuration information about windows authentication?

Comment: @LexLi I had FRT enabled for 200-999. They only seem to be 401.2 errors, before and after the credentials prompt when the client visits the virtual directory.

Comment: @samwu I have included a screenshot of the webServer/security/authentication/Windows Authentication config for the virtual directory. Use appPool credentials is disabled, kernel mode is enabled. Please let me know if you want something else.

Comment: You need to provide valid credentials at prompt multiple times so that IIS FRT can record the actual error (401.1 or 401.3 or 401.5 for example). Besides, you need to see into the actual HTTP packets and learn the actual credentials passed between the browser and server (tools like Wireshark/Fiddler are commonly used). Escalate to your domain administrators who should have the expertise to guide you through.